# How to add images in MaterialDatatable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `MaterialDatatable` in react-app this is working fine but now I want to add country icons with country names so how can I add images with table value?

My Code:-

```
<MaterialDatatable
    columns={headers}
    data={items}
    options={options}
/>
```

`items` is coming from below list:-

```
  export function getHeaders() {   return [
    {
      name: 'Username',
      field: 'username',
      type: 'string'
    },
    {
      name: 'Country',
      field: 'countryName',
      type: 'string',
      className: 'lftAlign',
    },
    {
      name: 'Name',
      field: 'fullName',
      type: 'string'
    }] }
```

Package Link:-
https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-datatable

**Countries flag images will be come from below array:-**

```
const countries = [
  {
    value: '1',
    title: 'Afghanistan',
    icon: '/flags/afghanistan.png'
  },
  {
    value: '2',
    title: 'Albania',
    icon: '/flags/albania.png'
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of what country values you have and some of the icons you would like to use?

Comment: Basically I need to add images with datatables values.

Comment: Rohit I understood the problem in the first place. I wondered about the details of the problem.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad I updated my question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `customValue` for that purpose:

[image]

See: https://github.com/Diaver/material-datatable

There is a sandbox example at https://codesandbox.io/s/lp8pvk1zk9?file=/index.js:0-1728:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MaterialDatatable from "material-datatable";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const columns = [
      { name: "Name", field: "name" },
      { name: "Title", field: "title" },
      { name: "Location", field: "location" },
      { name: "Age", field: "age" },
      { name: "Salary", field: "salary" },
      {
        name: "Name and Title Custom Column",
        field: "salary",
        options: {
          noHeaderWrap: true,
          width: 200,
          customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
            return `${value.name} (${value.title})`;
          }
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Custom Render",
        field: "salary2",
        options: {
          noHeaderWrap: true,
          width: 200,
          customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
            return <h4>{value.name}</h4>;
          },
          customValue: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => value.name,
          customSortValue: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => value.name
        }
      }
    ];

    const data = [
      {
        name: "Name 1",
        title: "Title 1",
        location: "Location 1",
        age: 30,
        salary: 10
      },
      {
        name: "Name 2",
        title: "Title 2",
        location: "Location 2",
        age: 31,
        salary: 11
      }
    ];

    const options = {
      filterType: "dropdown",
      responsive: "scroll"
    };

    return (
      <MaterialDatatable
        title={"ACME Employee list"}
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Note that the relevant part is

```
      {
        name: "Custom Render",
        field: "salary2",
        options: {
          noHeaderWrap: true,
          width: 200,
          customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
            return <h4>{value.name}</h4>;
          },
          customValue: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => value.name,
          customSortValue: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => value.name
        }
      }
```

Note that we have a `customValue` as

```
customValue: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => value.name,
```

You could have something like

```
customValue: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => value.icon,
```

Yes, I know, this only displays the relative path. But, instead of that, you can change this to return something like

```
`<img src="${value.icon}">`
```

the above is just a dummy example. You can replace it with a more React-like code and you can even put there some components.